# Creating paged-scrolling tile on Microsoft Band?

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm creating two `FlowPanels`, inside these two `FlowPnaels` there are a text box and a button, these two `FlowPanels` are contained in single `PageLayout` that laying the elements horizontally, the problem is that when i scroll the tile in my band, its not a paged scroll like the other tiles (messages, email, etc) in the band.

Is it because I’m only using a single page? And can i use more than one page in a tile? How can i add more pages to tiles?

Answer (score 0):

"How can I add more pages to tiles?"

Section 2.7.6 of the Microsoft Band Public SDK document states:

When setting the content of a tile page, you specify the tile’s Guid and the page’s Guid. If the page Guid matches one of the 8 current pages of the tile, then the content will update that existing page. If the page Guid does not match any of those current pages, then a new page will be created to hold the content. New pages are added on the left, pushing any existing pages to the right and if the tile already has 8 pages then the oldest (rightmost) page will be discarded.

Note that layouts define the visual organization of a page's content. Each page specifies which layout should be used. A tile can have up to 5 different layouts defined.

When a tile has more than 1 page of content, it should be possible to scroll horizontally between the pages.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know what they are stating in the documentation. I was looking for code examples doing multiple pages in a tile, all the examples in the document dont do that.

Comment: Ok. Section 2.7.7.3 shows how to add a single page in a Windows app. Step #6 is where the page is added. The code calls "Guid.NewGuid()" to generate a Guid, then creates a PageData object using that Guid, then passes that PageData object to "SetPagesAsync(tileGuid, pageData) to add the page to the tile. If that code were in a loop (generating a new Guid each iteration) then it would add a new page to the tile on each iteration.